# export Gridview to Excel (2010)

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to export Gridview to excel. My code use to work just a month ago, but now if I try to open the gridview, it gives me an error saying "file is corrupt". I am not sure what am I doing wrong. Below is my code:

```
   Private Sub ExportToExcel()
    FormatUtility.DateFormat(Date.Today.Month, dateMM)
    FormatUtility.DateFormat(Date.Today.Day, dateDD)
    Response.Clear()
    Response.Buffer = True
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel"
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=MyFiles.xls")
    Response.Charset = ""
    EnableViewState = False
    Dim tw As New System.IO.StringWriter
    Dim hw As New System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter(tw)

    Dim frm As HtmlForm = New HtmlForm()
    gvItems.Parent.Controls.Add(frm)
    frm.Attributes("runat") = "server"
    FormatExcelTransfer()
    frm.Controls.Add(gvItems)
    frm.RenderControl(hw)

    Response.Write(tw.ToString())
    Response.End()

End Sub
```

I didn't change my code, I am not sure if the something happened on the server side. I tried to change .xls to .xlsx for 2010, but that didn't work.

Comment: You haven't created an actual Excel file. You've created an HTML file and you're serving with an XLS extension. Don't do that. It's a terrible practice. Instead use a proper library such as [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/), [NPOI](http://npoi.codeplex.com/), or [Open XML SDK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb448854.aspx) to generate a proper XLSX file.

Comment: do you have nay example.

Comment: I have linked to three free libraries in previous comment. All have examples.

Comment: Thanks, I will EPPPlus package.